# Using aurelia templating engine enhance to dynamically add html

Tags: html, dynamic, aurelia, templating-engine

I'm trying to dynamically / programatically insert code into the DOM and have aurelia handle the inserted code like any other module.

The tricky part is that the inserted html has a `<compose view-model='A'></compose>` element which should itself load a module "A".

I have a [gistRun here](https://gist.run/?id=463daeae96ba368bfb56fc04d80d24d6)

**app.js**

```js
 loadmod(container, viewmodel){
      debugger;
      var childID = container + "child";
      var content = `<compose view-model='${viewmodel}' id='${childID}'></compose>`;
      $("#" + container).append("<div>" + content + "</div>");
      
      let el = $("#" + childID)[0];
      let view = this.templatingEngine.enhance({ element: el, bindingContext: {}, overrideContext: {}});
      view.bind();
      view.attached();  
    }
    loadm1(e){
      this.loadmod("m1holder", "m1");
    }
    loadm2(e){
      this.loadmod("m2holder", "m2");

    }
    loadm2again(e){
      this.loadmod("m2holderagain", "m2");
      
    }
```

```html
<template>
    <div>Stuff here</div>
    <button click.delegate="loadm1($event)">Load M1</button>
        <button click.delegate="loadm2($event)">Load M2</button>
        <button click.delegate="loadm2again($event)">Load Another M2</button>
    <div id="m1holder"></div>
    <div id="m2holder"></div>
    <div id="m2holderagain"></div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are attempting to enhance an element directly. You need to enhance a parent element which contains nodes to be enhanced. The Templating Engine looks for a parentNode when it does the enhancement logic.

See [this updated Gist.run example](https://gist.run/?id=a7939b81f498d4e6e18fd83586522f5d) for how it should work.